# AppEngine bulkloader, high replication store and python27 runtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Can anyone clarify the situation here?

I've used the Bulkloader with Python25 and old/master slave databases.

I've also used it (for uploading data only) with Python25 and the high replication datastore, despite what it says here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

> This document applies to apps that use the master/slave datastore. If 
>   your app uses the High Replication datastore, it is possible to copy 
>   data from the app, but Google does not currently support this use 
>   case.

However, I'm now trying the Bulkloader with the high replication datastore and Python27 and it appears to be irretrievably broken. It actually seems to bypass the authentication step, even though I am passing my email correctly to `appcfg.py`

Has anyone else tried this? Can anyone confirm which components Bulkloader will/won't work with?

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace, code, error messages, or other relevant details. We can't possibly help without seeing specifically what you're doing.

Comment: OK I figured it out. I had a remote_api handler specified in the python25 app.yaml but not the python27 version. You need to run the python27 version with 'threadsafe: False' else appengine will complain about the CGI- style handler. Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You can use the 'remote_api' built-in handler in order to enable remote_api. The built-in handler takes care of the handler style. Also, please update the question and close it.

Comment: @Justin, seconding Takashi's comment 2.5 years ago, could you **please** update and close this Q...?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you "had a **remote_api** handler specified in the *python25* **app.yaml** but not the *python27* version.

You need to run the **python27** version with `threadsafe: False` [or] *appengine* will complain about the *CGI - style handler*."

'

Please answer the question instead of just commenting next time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I downgraded from GAELauncher 1.27 to 1.26, and the authentication started working again.

Temporary solution: go to https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured/ to get version 1.9.26

Submitted bug report: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=340